# Java Graphics2D rotate method causes all things painted afterwards to jitter

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

I have experienced a bit of a problem with javas rotate method. In the following example, I am first calling the rotate method, drawing the rectangle to be rotated and then calling the rotate method again in the exact opposite direction, therefore painting the following rectangles with a 0 degree rotation. However there seems to be a problem with all things painted afterwards, as the second rectangle experiences something I can only describe as a jitter in the y-axis. This does of course only affect things painted after the rotate method is called. Help would be greatly appreciated, as it really is annoying to look at.

```
package pack;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int degrees = 0;
    public Timer timer;

    public Test() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setContentPane(new paintLabel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        timer= new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {degrees++;repaint();}
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public class paintLabel extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), 100, 185);
            g2d.fillRect(40, 125, 120, 120);
            g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(degrees), 100, 185);
            g2d.fillRect(225, 125, 120, 120);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {new Test();}
}
```

Comment: What is this `repaint();` doing in your paintComponent method? Get it out and place it into the Timer's ActionListener where it belongs.

Comment: Yes but that does not at all answer my question

Comment: this code works perfectly on my computer...

Comment: Well it works on mine too, it´s just that if you look at the left rectangle, the top and sometimes the bottom oscillates a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with precision since  you are not rotating an image.  You are rotating the `Graphics context`.  The reason the other image didn't rotate is because you simply returned the context to its previous state.  You need to then rotate about the center of the second image.

First you were were doing some things incorrectly.

- Don't extend `JFrame` (you weren't overriding anything so just use an instance);
- Do extend `JPanel` and put that in the Frame
- Add the label to the panel
- Override `getPreferredSize` to size the `JLabel`

Here try this. If you turn on anti-aliasing the jitter goes away.  It also tends to smooth out any rough edges.  The other image is rotated in the opposite direction.  Note that this could just be done inside of `paintComponent` without the `JLabel` class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.renderable.RenderableImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test extends JPanel {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int degrees = 0;
    public Timer timer;

    public Test() {
        f.add(this);
        add(new PaintLabel());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        timer= new Timer(50,(ae)->{degrees++; repaint();});
        
        timer.start();
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center on screen
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    

    public class PaintLabel extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400,400);
        }
        
        @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), 100, 185);
            g2d.fillRect(40, 125, 120, 120);
            g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(degrees), 100, 185);
            g2d.fillRect(225, 125, 120, 120);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();}
}
```

Comment: this answer is far more elegant and gives a lot of input about misused components & rendering - if i could accept i would choose your answer rather than mine!

Comment: i tried your code and the outcome is really smooth!

Comment: @MartinFrank  Thanks!  but don't worry about it.  I also added the correct rotation to rotate the second image.  Check it out.

Comment: @MartinFrank BTW, you were on the right track if one wanted to rotate a polygon by adjusting the coordinates.  The shape would degrade due to rounding errors by continually recalculating the coordinates.  But when you rotate the graphics context, it doesn't really affect the image.

Answer (score 1):

if you rotate slower the effect is visible - sorry for not noticing that on faster rotation

if you draw a `Rectangle`, than all points of the rectangle are transformed and afterwards drawn. this leads to **rounding issues**. if you want to lock your rectangle you have to use a rectangle with fixed proportions, namely a `Image`! that prevents your jittering...

```
public class paintLabel extends JLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final Image img = createRectImage();

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), 100d, 185d);
//        g2d.fillRect(40, 125, 120, 120);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 40,125, null);
        g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(degrees), 100d, 185d);
        g2d.fillRect(225, 125, 120, 120);
    }
}
```

```
private Image createRectImage() {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(120,120, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0,0,120,120);
    return image;
}
```

compare the output!

Comment: The rectangle which is rotating certainly looks a lot better. The second rectangle remains unchanged though. It still oscillates.

Comment: Oh nevermind I just forgot to also use the createRectImage method for the second image. Well thank you a lot, that works perfectly then